# Is possible to improve the activation time of a conda environment?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, anaconda

*First, please **apologize** if any mistake and the inconvenience. I'm new with conda and anaconda*.

I'm struggling with the time that takes the activation of my conda environment (up to 10 seconds) - *the 'activate' is slow*.

Is the any way to make this timeless? Some people recommend using the root instead of the environment. I would like to keep using environments for the different needs of each project.

I'm using Windows 10 (Home - version 1607), 15.9GB usable RAM, 64-bits OS and x64 processor with Intel i7 2.00GHz CPU.

Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.21
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : 2.1.8
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.4
   root environment : C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\Antonio\.conda\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : C:\Users\Antonio\.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.12.4 CPython/3.5.2 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
      administrator : False
```

Comment: So basic like having a fast computer. My issue got resolved with my new laptop

Comment: `Windows 10 (Home - version 1607), 15.9GB usable RAM, 64-bits OS and x64 processor with Intel i7 2.00GHz CPU` did it took up to 10 seconds with this computer? or is this the new computer you are using?

Comment: Windows 10 (Home - version 1607), 15.9GB usable RAM, 64-bits OS and x64 processor with Intel i7 2.00GHz CPU, is the old computer

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8609) contains some leads on profiling what's taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it matters how long it takes to activate an Anaconda environment as long as it is within 2 minutes.
However, as a person using both Linux and Windows with Anaconda, I can say that activating environments on Windows takes significantly longer than it does on Linux.
Given that my Windows machine is also much more powerful than my Linux machine (gaming desktop vs. standard laptop) and that I have more and bigger environments on Linux, I am pretty sure it simply has to do with the Windows version of Anaconda or Windows itself.

Comment: I think the matter is a bit more complicated. I use Anaconda in Windows and an environment activates fast, usually in under a second. I also use Anaconda in a Linux environment but inside a Virtual Machine. I log into a high-performance computing shared environment (PBSPro) inside the Virtual Machine and it takes anywhere between 5 seconds to 5 minutes to activate an environment.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that conda just does packages freshness check when it starts, over the internet.

In your `condarc`, try to set

```
auto_update_conda: False
```

If that does not help, also try

```
offline: True
```

(See [the docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.htm).)

Comment: Dear 900, thanks! I tried both ways and measured the time with the same result with and without.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Be careful with `offline: True` as that may not update/resolve your dependencies and may lead to version mismatches if you install something (at least for me it fixed a mismatch after I disabled `offline: True` again)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try just expanding your path, if you just need a program out of your conda environment, e.g. in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin:$PATH
```

That takes like no time. If you need more out of the environment though, try the other options.